# No way to resolve conflict between "XYZ" and XYZ"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

We just did a merge(TFS) between two branches. But now when I compile, I've this error:

```
No way to resolve conflict between 
"AA.BB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" 
and 
"AA.BB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bfd296a93930d932". 
Choosing "AA.BB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

"`AA.BB`" is one of our project, I've checked that we only reference it as a project. And we have only project named like this.

Does someone knows why this error is happening? And where this PublicKeyToken error can come from?

What I already tried:

- Remove all reference to this project and make again the references
- Search if one of those project was having a copyLocal = true(not the case) or referencing directly a DLL(not the case)

Note that:

- The build is considered as succeed but when I launch the application I got errors(basically an error saying that this dll doesn't match the manifest)
- If I got in the classes that uses this, I've no errors

Comment: Are you using late signing?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't know what this is, so I guess that the answer is no But one thing that is possible is that our build server change some assembly info

Comment: It shouldn't change that *after* building the files. You have double-checked that you only have project references, and that you don't have a reference to the build output directly? ie. to the bin\release\AA.BB.dll ?

Comment: Yes, it's the first think I checked(and to be sure, I removed all reference of this project, and added them again). I see that we currently Sign the Assembly, with a key AA.BB.snk But the "Delay sign only" checkbox isn't checked

Comment: @J4N, from the error message you posted above, we will check that these two assemblies have the same version number; but one has publicKeyToken and another is not. So did you ever installed the assembly into GAC? If so, how about you uninstall it, and re-add the project reference?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the issue, I post it since maybe it can help someone in the future.

The issue was that before the Merge, there were some project which were having a different output directory.

So, when doing the rebuild, some project were finding multiple reference of the same project in different directory.

The solution is quite simple: Delete manually once the output directory and you're good :)